# What wireless temperature monitoring systems should I look into?

Tags: home-automation, temperature, meter

I'd like to monitor and log temperature on few locations in my home. Wireless monitoring with normal consumer batteries etc would be preferable for the sensors. I have an Mac OSX server running at my home where I could log the temperatures and browse the data. I live in Finland, so something that's too specific for the US will not work.

Do you have any good suggestions or experiences on what wireless temperature sensors and system to use? I'd prefer something cheap but not too DIY as this thing is just a novelty for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is using Arduino based microcontroller. I recommend [JeeNode](http://jeelabs.org) for integrated wireless.

For basic one "server" plus one remote sensor you need two JeeNodes, USB adapter, temperature sensor and battery, all for around 55 €. You need to know how to solder electronic components and program in C. Each additional sensor would cost about 20 €.

Here is [example project for temperature sensor using Arduino](http://www.danielandrade.net/2008/07/05/temperature-sensor-arduino/) (will work on JeeNode as well). You have to add wireless code as well, starting with [this skeleton](http://jeelabs.org/2011/05/07/rf12-skeleton-sketch/).

So, not so cheap and certainly pretty advanced DIY. ;-)

Comment: Heh, thanks. I think it's a bit too much DIY for now.

Comment: As this answer seems to be the most valued by users, I'm going to accept it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for the logging software [thermd](http://www.klein.com/thermd/devices.shtml) contains extensive notes about the supported devices, as well as a comparison in terms of cost and functionality.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution I found after I asked the question myself. I have not yet tested it, but it looks promising. I will not accept this as an answer unless I actually find this one to work. I just wanted to add it here for it might give ideas for someone else wondering the same question.

Basicly the plan goes like this:

1. Get an radio tranceiver (transmitter and receiver) from: http://www.telldus.com/products/tellstick_duo
2. Get a wireless temperature sensor (or maybe even multiple) something like this: http://www.clasohlson.com/fi/Lis%C3%A4anturi/Pr361797000 (check from the telldus forums that it works)

If anyone else has experience with this approach, I'd love to hear about it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a product called ElertUs for about $200, which uses a WiFi sensor + a smartphone app or website.  It is available for purchase on either the [manufacturer's website](http://elertus.com) or on [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00ERNHBOE) ([note seller feedback](http://www.amazon.com/gp/aag/main?ie=UTF8&marketplaceID=ATVPDKIKX0DER&seller=A3M0XHAP347016)).

ElertUs allows you to monitor temperature, humidity plus a bunch of other conditions. From the manufacturer:

> A simple to use monitoring solution that gives people the capability
>   to know what's happening to their important things at anytime and from
>   anywhere!
>
> The Elertus Sensor monitors and receive changes in:
>
> ```
> Door opens and closes
> Movement
> Temperature Levels
> Humidity Levels
> Light Levels
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I was considering doing just this with some XRF modules and something like a Raspberry Pi

[Ciseco](http://shop.ciseco.co.uk/temperature-xrf-development-sensor-dallas-ds18b20/) sell modules for this (inclding USB XRF receivers that I expect would be usable in a Mac).

There are probably many many other vendors.

Alternatively I imagine Oregon Scientific or similar makers have wireless weather-stations with multiple remote wireless temperature sensors.

Answer (score -1):

There is a "How to" to develop your own low-cost temperature monitoring at the blogspot -
http://lowcostsystem.blogspot.com